# How long insert into Oracle database spend time?

Tags: java, oracle

I will insert data into Oracle's two tables.The table_1 row size is 912 Byte.The table_2 row size is 335 Byte.

For table_1,I will insert 263520000 rows of data.So,The Size of the table_1 is 223.8Gb.

For table_2,I will insert 27816000 rows of data.So,The Size of the table_2 is 8.678Gb.

I use two Java processes,there are no processes with 100 threads.So,I want to know how long will it take me to insert all the data into the database?

Comment: Any indexes? Any referential integrity constraints?

Comment: Time will depend on  lot of factors, like your machine speed for java processes, server speed for Oracle DB, indexes, network latency, etcetera. I suggest you to do a little test, inserting 10000 records and calculate how much did it take. Then you can extrapolate these results for larger datasets and have an idea.

Comment: Short answer: it will take as long as it needs to. Long answer will depend (among other things) on: 1. how did you write your SQL `insert` statement, 2. Are there any indexes on these tables, 3. Are there any constraints on these tables. 4. Is there enough space allocated in each table for the data being inserted (is there a need to expand table storage space). 5. How long does it take to expand table storate and how long does it take to physically write bytes to storage file system.

Comment: As others have said, insert performance depends, can you using a bulk loader like sql*Loader or and ETL tool?  What is the disk layout of your database, what is the controller bandwidth, disk IOP's, etc.  As a rough guesstimate, assuming decent hardware, I would guess about a little over an hour using bulk load breaking up the file into multiple chunks, using Java and batch, probably closer to two hours depending on how clean the data is, errors slow down the performance tremendously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, this will highly depend on your system.  Are there indexes?  Are you going a direct path load?  What kind of storage are you using, specifically, are you connected storage or on a SAN and is the SAN spinning disk or solid state?  To get an answer to your question, also as mentioned, you'll have to either test the full load to get the answer, or test load with a subset of the data and extrapolate out.

If you have to load 100's of millions of rows, using Java may not be the best solution?  Other data import options exists to load data that will be better than java.  SQL loader and datapump to name a couple.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you an idea of what *can* ben done using the right tools and the right algorithms (ie set based; direct path; parallelism), I just loaded just over 7 Billion rows (across three tables), which is about 1 TB of files, in about 10 mins.

Answer (score 0):

There are published benchmarks that may help to give you a ball-park figure.

[Here's one article](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_insert_tuning.htm) that may be relevant.

Note that the article references various techniques including bulk-loading tools. I would strongly suggest that you investigate using such tools. A simplistic Java program

```
for each record
    read data
    write to database
```

is likely to be noticeably slower than such tools, not least because you'll be using a transaction per insert.